# how to remove empty rows from view

Tags: views, 7, blocks, entities

how to remove empty rows from view(block) ?
I have a created a View block using field collection even empty condition are enabled in the fields settings still im getting empty rows PFA for image 2 in that only view-row-95 has values rest all the view-row are empty .
[image: block settings]
[image: empty rows]
[image: setting of fields]

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Please check check-box "Count the number 0 as empty" and test this again.

Comment: @ScottJoudry I have Cleared Cache .getting same result

Comment: @JayendraKainthola I have enabled "Count the number 0 as empty" and cleared cache.still getting same result

Answer (score 2):

In this given image(second image), it is clear that there is a value " "(space) coming for the field **Footer Col3**.

Check in **Footer Col3** field settings or in any custom module if you are set any default value for that field.